# How to show array items inside text area with new line which is functional with angular search pipe

Tags: angular

```
 <p>All users &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText" class="form-control srch" placeholder="Search"></p>
          <textarea class="form-control" readonly>{{couponUsers | searchUser: searchText}}</textarea>
```

Earlier I was using this to create new line instead of comma and it was working

```
this.couponUsers = this.couponUsers.toString().replace(/,/g, "\n");
```

Then I added a pipe to search which required me to remove the above line so that this.couponUsers remains an array.

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
        name: 'searchUser'
    })
    export class searchUser implements PipeTransform {
        transform(array: [], searchTerm: any) {
            if (!array || !searchTerm) {
                return array;
            }
            return array.filter((user: any) =>
            user.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1
            );
        }
    }
```

Now the search works but the items in the text area are separated by comma and I want new line instead.

I tried this, it adds a new line but the comma remains and its shown at the beginning of every new line the first char is the comma.

```
for (let index = 0; index < this.couponUsers.length; index++) {
  this.couponUsers[index] = this.couponUsers[index] + '\n';
}
```

couponUsers array example in console

```
Array(2)
0: "Mark ee dsdsds@gmail.com"
1: "Dave Lee daveesd@gmail.com"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

In the textarea it is shown as `Mark ee dsdsds@gmail.com,Dave Lee daveesd@gmail.com`

Comment: Maybe you can print some of the data of the couponUsers array. For me it sounds like the commas are part of the list entry, are they?

Comment: there is no comma in the original array just the text area rendering it i think. updated example of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `Pipe` to return a string of your filtered users with the linebreak included by using the `join` method.

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
        name: 'searchUser'
    })
    export class searchUser implements PipeTransform {
        transform(array: [], searchTerm: any) {
            if (!array || !searchTerm) {
                return array;
            }
            return array.filter((user: any) =>
            user.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1
            ).join("\n");
        }
    }
```